# Ignoring links, checkboxes.. in an editable html field using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Sorry for the constant question!! I have a table that displays records of data from my database. To make life easier, I have make it editable using jquery so that a user can click right an area an edit right away without redirecting to a different page. 
A couple of questions.. how can i refine the below code so that when an area on the table with checkboxes and links is clicked, it will not respond/not editable? 
Also, the editing function does not fully work at the moment and im having problems trying to figure out where the problem is. The table responds to everything defined in the jquery below but does not update my database.

There is my jquery code edit.js

```
$(function() {
$('tbody').on('click','td',function() {
displayForm( $(this) );
});

});

function displayForm( cell ) {

var column = cell.attr('class'),
id = cell.closest('tr').attr('id'),
cellWidth = cell.css('width'),
prevContent = cell.text()

form = '<form action="javascript: this.preventDefault"><input type="text" name="newValue" value="'+prevContent+'" /><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+id+'" />'+'<input type="hidden" name="column" value="'+column+'" /></form>';

cell.html(form).find('input[type=text]')
.focus()
.css('width',cellWidth);

cell.on('click', function(){return false});

cell.on('keydown',function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {//13 == enter
changeField(cell, prevContent);//update field
} else if (e.keyCode == 27) {//27 == escape
cell.text(prevContent);//revert to original value
cell.off('click'); //reactivate editing
}
});

}

function changeField( cell, prevContent ) {

cell.off('keydown');
var url = 'edit.php?edit&',
input = cell.find('form').serialize();

$.getJSON(url+input, function(data) {
if (data.success)
cell.html(data.value);
else {
alert("There was a problem updating the data.  Please try again.");
cell.html(prevContent);
}

});
cell.off('click');
}
```

And in my edit.php I have the following:

```
<?php
include ("common.php");

if (isset($_GET['edit'])){
$column = $_GET['column'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$newValue = $_GET["newValue"];

$sql = 'UPDATE compliance_requirement SET $column = :value WHERE ComplianceID = :id';
$stmt = $dbh ->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $newValue);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$response['success'] = $stmt->execute();
$response['value']=$newValue;

echo json_encode($response);
}?>
```

and finally my html..

```
<div class="compTable">
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Compliance Name</th><th>Compliance Goal</th><th>Compliance  Description</th><th>Opions</th><th>Invite</th></tr></thead>

<tbody>
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM compliance_requirement';
$results = $db->query($sql);
$rows = $results->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
echo '<tr id="'.$row['ComplianceID'].'">';
echo '<td class="crsDesc">'.$row['ComplianceName'].'</td>
<td >'.$row['ComplianceGoal'].'</td> 
<td >'.$row['ComplianceDescription'].'</td>
<td ><a href =inviteObstacle.php?action=invite&id=name1> InviteObstacle </a></td>
<td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"> <input type="checkbox" name="query_myTextEditBox">
</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Your help is much appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution for identifying editable cells would be give those cells a class `editable` in your php output, then change your selector for `td` click handler to

```
$('tbody').on('click','td.ditable',function() {
```

As for updating database...need to determine if the ajax request from `$.getJSON` is being made. You can inspect this within browser console network tab. Also look for errors in console. Request ( if made) will show status, what is sent, what is returned etc

Need to use that as start point to help determine if preoblem lies in server code ( would get a 500 status) or in browser code.

If you provide live html sample ( not php ) from browser source view can create test demos to see what your javascript code is doing . Putting the html and javascript into jsfiddle.net and saving creates a demo that anyone can test out

Comment: thanks for that.. that solved my first problem. I completely didn't think of that!! However, i still don't know how to go about the 2nd problem, there is no error showing on the console

Comment: well can you see request being made in network tab? Have you tried logging to console within your submit handler?

Comment: yes a request is bn made in the network tab to the http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.map url and a status code of 304 (Not modified). I have no idea what that means.. really appreciate your help

Comment: no...that's just a jQuery resource being loaded. Looking for the url you set up to send data too. Going to play wit ajax will need to understand the http request status codes...good page on wikipedia for that